# How to disable objects in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I want to disable a button in silverlight, does it has a disable property that can bind to a variable?

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable a button, you can use

```
myButton.IsEnabled = false;
```

All [UIElements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabled.aspx) have this property.

Answer (score 2):

If you have some sort of ViewModel with a `bool` property

```
public bool CanDoSomething
{
    get { return _canDoSomething; }
    set
    {
        if (_canDoSomething != value)
        {
            _canDoSomething = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CanDoSomething");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can bind the Button in XAML with something like

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CanDoSomething}" />
```